# Python3, pyodbc, SQL Server: Supplying Unicode and ANSI string as needed

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, unicode, pyodbc

I use Python, and currently Python3, to access legacy (read "not going to be changed") databases with ANSI char/varchar columns/indexes.

I just discovered a major performance problem (with a new database over which I have full control) was solved by converting the database to nchar/nvarchar ([see this article](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/18/troubleshooting-sql-index-performance-on-varchar-columns/)), so that my queries, columns and indexes were all aligned to use Unicode.

Which begs the question, and I have thus far been unable to Google it, how do I give pyodbc a non-Unicode string in Python3 so that it correctly passes the string on to ODBC/SQL Server as a non-unicode string? This has significant performance implications for a number of e.g. data-mining applications.

This seems to work, but is it correct?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect( connection_string )
curr = conn.cursor()
aString = 'Howdy!'
query = 'select * from aTable where aColumn = ?'
results = curr.execute( q, [aString.encode('ascii')] )
```

Alternately/additionally, is it more appropriate and/or possible to build a Unicode index over a non-Unicode column in SQL Server? (I have sufficient control of the database to add indexes).

Answer (score 1):

> is it correct?

Based on what SQL Profiler and SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) say while testing with SQL Server ODBC under Windows, it seems so, assuming that the string values really will be restricted to ASCII characters.

If we just pass `[aString]` as the query parameter, SQL Profiler shows that pyodbc sends this

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(6)',N'select * from aTable where aColumn = @P1',N'Howdy!'
```

and if we ask SSMS to show us the estimated execution plan for

```sql
select * from aTable where aColumn = N'Howdy!'
```

it tells us that it expects to do an Index Scan.

However, if we pass `[aString.encode('ascii')]` as the query parameter, SQL Profiler shows that pyodbc sends this

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varbinary(6)',N'select * from aTable where aColumn = @P1',0x486F77647921
```

and if we ask SSMS to show us the estimated execution plan for

```sql
select * from aTable where aColumn = 0x486F77647921
```

it tells us that it expects to do an Index Seek.

A "Seek" is usually better than a "Scan", so if the queries actually return the correct results I'd expect better performance from using the encoded parameter.

Comment: You took my "prove it works" a step further experimentally, but your answer is not quite satisfying. I am, in particular, a bit scared by the fact that SQL Server is treating the query as varbinary and not as varchar/char. Ultimately, I would like to know how to correctly supply ANSI strings to ANSI databases, and/or performance guard ANSI databases against Unicode queries.

Comment: Point of interest: pyodbc under Python2 does `exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(6)',N'SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE aColumn=@P1','Howdy!'`. However, Python3 does not have "plain" (non-Unicode) strings, just `strings` (for Unicode) and `bytes` (for non-Unicode).